# How to determine the stability of an aerodynamic shape in ANSYS Fluent

Tags: aerodynamics, ansys, stability, fluent

I have the aerodynamic outer mold line file of a drone. The first task of the school project is to verify that the drone is stable. First, I used the 2021R2 version of ANSYS Fluent to try to find the force acting on the top and bottom surface of the drone like how they did it in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPjS201TQvI. I created an enclosure of the drone, delected the volume occupied by the drone, and mesh the final product. Then I run calculations, but I can only the see the pressure at one thin segment of the drone using the "create plane" function. I then tried to bisect the enclosure and mesh the rear part of the enclosure. But it just won't mesh and I am not sure how to change "configuration" of my mesh. I am under the impression that we can generate a force report, but I can't find any button that resembles those that are shown on answers I saw on google.

Comment: Have you checked the examples in Ansys help?

Comment: There isn't similar problems, or anything that resembles what I am trying to do.

Comment: We don't normally handle software instruction here. I think there's a SE for fluid flow computation, but maybe not for Fluent.